# Mutated animals in X-men (/Ultimate X-men)

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, mutant

In [*Ultimate X-Men* #18](https://marvel.fandom.com/Ultimate_X-Men_Vol_1_18) when Xavier talks about how he and MacTaggert started their work, he mentions "Boys made of steam, dogs made of ice cream." Even if this is a humorous remark, it still seems to imply that animals being super-mutated somehow isn't unheard of. Is this established in any other place in the *X-Men* universes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the *Ultimate X-Men* universe, there are a number of mutated animals who appear in the series. One of them, Prosimian is one of several super-evolved apes freed by the Brotherhood of Mutants from a lab. Prosimian is responsible for arranging the rescue and psychic deprogramming of Magneto during *Ultimate X-Men 25*.

[image: Prosimian is pictured upside down, with typically over-muscled superhero legs in dark tights, bare shoulders and upper arms covered lightly in thick dark hair, massive forearms and hands in elbow-length gloves. He has a slightly-flattened chimpanzee-like face and has a red bandana with a gold star on his head. His chest is crossed with two ammunition belts and he is holding a machine gun in his hands firing on automatic; a cascade of shells falls away to the left.]

Answer (score 2):

Some speculate that Wolverine himself is a mutated animal.  Take this sampling from *X-men* #103...

[image: Wolverine, shown with only his head, left shoulder, and right forearm entering the frame from the right, pursues a small green-clad humanoid with a wispy white beard along a pavement in the rain. Wolverine: "No way, bub. The Wolverine don't believe in leprechauns." Leprechaun: "Suit yerself. Maybe leprechauns don't believe in talkin' wolverines, either. Now, are ye comin' with me or no?"]

Some believe that the Leprechaun is giving a clue into Len Wein's (creator of *Wolverine*) idea that "Wolverine is an actual wolverine". Couple it with this from *X-men* #98 and you may have a convincing case...

[image: Wolverine, stripped to the waist and wearing light brown pants, is stapled to a wall. In the foreground two men in superhero costumes speak. 1 (behind): "I dunno, sir--is this Wolverine a mutant? His readings are nothing like the others." 2 (front): "The Sentinels say he is..."]

Comment: I believe this is also explored in the Earth-X/Universe-X/Paradise-X maxi series that Wolverine is a member of the Moon Tribe and Sabertooth is a member of the Bear tribe, their mortal enemies.

Comment: True: some people speculate this. False: this was the creator's original intention. Len Wein has gone on the record saying that that was people after him. "[The mutated wolverine thing came about long after I was no longer involved with the book. I'm not certain if the idea was first suggested by Chris Claremont, the late much-missed Dave Cockrum, or John Byrne when he came aboard as artist, but it most certainly DID NOT start with me.](http://lenwein.blogspot.com/2009/02/say-what.html)"

Comment: Also of note, Catseye's origins are indeterminate as to whether she was born a human girl who could turn into a cat from an early age or a cat who has learned to take human shape. She believes herself to be a cat.